# Upload Edge extension to web store with existing extension ID

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

We are porting our Chrome extension to Edge and our extension already has an extension ID that our native messaging applications rely on.

In Chrome you have control over the id of the newly created extension by including the "key.pem" file in the first upload of the extension package.  But that is not working in the Edge Store, it seems to always create a new extension ID.

Is there a way to force the store to use our existing extension ID?

Comment: I received an answer from Microsoft support. The web store simply doesn't support this yet. You have to create your listing to get the new ID you can't use an existing private key to create an extension with a pre-determined ID.

Comment: Thanks for updating us with the answer to the said question. It can help other community members in future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Is your native message application rely on **chrome.runtime.connectNative** application?

If yes, I suggest you set **allowedorigins** to "**extension://[Microsoft-Catalog-extensionID]**" in your native messaging host manifest file.

So I think you have to use **Microsoft-Catalog-extensionID** and you can't use that existing extension Id.

I go this information in the documentation.

> If your Extension exchanges messages with a native application using
>   chrome.runtime.connectNative API, ensure that you set allowedorigins
>   to "extension://[Microsoft-Catalog-extensionID]" in your native
>   messaging host manifest file. This enables the app to identify the
>   Extension.

Reference:

[Port Chrome Extension To Microsoft (Chromium) Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/port-chrome-extension)